# Ruby Hash is including extra values for a single key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I've tried to build a hash multiple ways, but when I use it in a `grouped_options_for_select` tag, there are extra values that aren't in my original hash. Here are two ways I've tried to build my hash:

```
UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED = {
  "Dry" =>     ["oz", "lb", "g", "kg"],
  "Liquid" =>  ["floz", "gal", "ml", "L"],
  "Other" =>   ["each"]
}.freeze
```

and a bit more explicit and very wordy:

```
UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED = {}
UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED[:dry] = ["oz", "lb", "g", "kg"]
UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED[:liquid] = ["floz", "gal", "ml", "L"]
UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED[:other] = ["each"]
UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED.freeze
```

But the `grouped_options_for_select` always includes "floz" and "each" in the first section ("dry"). Please see attached image.

I forgot to add my form element code:

`<%= form.select :unit_of_measure, grouped_options_for_select(UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED) %>`

As per Guiseppe in another comment, I tried `<%= form.select :unit_of_measure, UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED %>` with the same result.

Something that does seem really weird is when I go into the console after triggering an error, my `UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED` hash shows this:

`{:dry=>["oz", "lb", "g", "kg", ["floz", "gal", "ml", "L"], ["each"]], :liquid=>["floz", "gal", "ml", "L"], :other=>["each"]}`

My guess is that's screwing up the HTML and getting confused. Does that help?

What am I missing? Thank you SO much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does it work the same way when you provide array instead of hash?

Comment: Works as expected.  Sure you are pointing at the right hash?

Comment: Can you please share the generated HTML instead of the screenshot?

Comment: I think you do not need `grouped_options_for_select`  see [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-groups) for `form.select`.

Comment: Same for me as for @dbugger, works as expected. Are you using some specific form builder or similar that could be messing it up? Otherwise my guess would be incorrect hash as well.

Comment: I'd look at all the code that may be creating or updating the hash -- the wrong hash is the root of the problem -- it is displaying exactly what is in the hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be inclined to concur with the suspicion that something mangling your hash is to blame. To find out what, try a deeper freeze:

```
UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED = {
  dry: %w(oz lb g kg),
  liquid: %w(floz gal ml L),
  other: %w(each)
}.transform_values(&:freeze).freeze
```

This'll (hopefully) throw a `FrozenError`, and accompanying illuminating stack trace, from wherever deep in the app/framework is screwing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are calling `form.select` inside the `erb` tag.
You are supposed to pass a collection but instead, you are passing a `string` as the second argument.
You should pass `UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED` instead of  `grouped_options_for_select(UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED)` as in the following example:

```rb
<%= form.select :unit_of_measure, UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED %>.
```

If you look at [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-groups) you can find an example.

The `select` [helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select)

> Wraps ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper#select for form builders:

`ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper#select` [requires a collection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) as parameter.

Edited.

It could be the generetion of hidden fileds that you get by default
Try the following

```rb
<%= form.select :unit_of_measure, UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED, {include_hidden: false} %>
```

See [Documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) for details.

Comment: Shembrie Thanks for the initial help, but I tried `<%= form.select :unit_of_measure, UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED %>`, and it's the same result.

Comment: @KyleCarlson I edited the answer giving you another suggestion that is worth a try.

Comment: `UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED` is a hash not a string, and `grouped_options_for_select(UNITS_OF_MEASURE_GROUPED)` is what you would pass if you want a grouped select box.

Comment: @dbugger you should pass a `Hash` to `form.select` please see this [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-groups) or the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select).